# Need help extracting data from excel file

Tags: database, regex, excel, extract

I've got an excel file with a list of categories and their products, with each product having an associate price. And it's very poorly organized, it's something like this:

> **Cars**
>
> Subaru | $5200
>
> Toyota | $4300
>
> Lexus | $8600
>
> Ford | $7580
>
> **Trucks**
>
> Mercedes | $12200
>
> Suzuki | $8400

I basically need to extract data from this sheet and store it into a mysql database.
Everything in **bold** is a category, products are listed under a category up until the next category is encountered.

So on the categories table should end up looking like this

```
id  title
-----------
1   Cars
2   Trucks
```

And the products table like this

```
id  title     category_id price
---------------------------------
1   Subaru    1            5200
2   Toyota    1            4300
2   Lexus     1            8600
2   Ford      1            7580
2   Mercedes  2            12200
2   Suzuki    2            8400
```

It doesn't matter what tools / languages I could use to do this. It's a one-time extraction. Any pointers on how I could start working on this would be helpful enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a one off extraction, use vba to split the data into two seperate temporary sheets in excel then standard methods to insert then data into database.

code below assumes data is in a sheet named "Data" and starts at cell A1
Add two sheets called "Catagory" and "Product"

code loops through the data sheet, copying each row to the correct table sheet

```
Sub SplitData()
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim rCat As Range
    Dim rProd As Range
    Dim Cat As String
    Dim Prod As String
    Dim Price As Currency
    Dim Cat_ID As Long
    Dim Prod_ID As Long

    Set rData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, 1)
    Set rCat = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Catagory").Cells(1, 1)
    Set rProd = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Product").Cells(1, 1)

    rCat = "id"
    rCat.Offset(0, 1) = "title"
    Set rCat = rCat.Offset(1, 0)

    rProd = "id"
    rProd.Offset(0, 1) = "title"
    rProd.Offset(0, 2) = "catagory_id"
    rProd.Offset(0, 3) = "price"
    Set rProd = rProd.Offset(1, 0)

    Cat_ID = 0
    Prod_ID = 0

    Do While rData <> ""
        If rData.Font.Bold Then
            Cat = rData
            Cat_ID = Cat_ID + 1

            rCat = Cat_ID
            rCat.Offset(0, 1) = Cat

            Set rCat = rCat.Offset(1, 0)
        Else
            Prod = rData
            Price = rData.Offset(0, 1)
            Prod_ID = Prod_ID + 1

            rProd = Prod_ID
            rProd.Offset(0, 1) = Prod
            rProd.Offset(0, 2) = Cat_ID
            rProd.Offset(0, 3) = Price

            Set rProd = rProd.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        Set rData = rData.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: based upon new requirements described in comments below.

Use VBA inside of Excel to do the following. I'll describe using psudeo code:

```
string saveCategory;
readrow columnA, ColumnB;
if (columnA is bold)
{
   saveCategory = columnA;
   write saveCategory to category table;
}
else
{
   write to product table productname=ColumnA, productprice=columnB, category=saveCategory;
}
loop back to read next row until end of worksheet;
```

Comment: But saving as csv will lose formatting, remember that categories are marked as bold

Comment: You are trying to keep data in your tables Bold? Huh? The CSV file is just temporary so that you can populate your tables. If you know how you can use VBA and do it inside Excel, but I assumed you wanted a simple answer.

Comment: No, I don't want the save as bold in the table. The sheet that I am provided with defines categories as bold. If a row is bold, it is a category.

Comment: That may be true, but it seems they also don't have a price. Are you saying that one of your requirements for a solution is that it must detect bold text?

Comment: Yes, it must detect bold text.

Comment: Edited my answer to meet this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If available, I would use SQL Server Integration Services. It can handle record types in the source.

Comment: Will it detect that the cell is bold and then fill in the category for the next n records?